# Blowfish encryption in php

Tags: php, encryption, blowfish

I'm writing an encryption to my application and website, but I don't know how to correctly encrypt the string in php. Decryption is already done by this code:

```
function decrypt_blowfish($data,$key){
$iv=pack("H*" , substr($data,0,16));
$key=pack("H*" , $key);
$x =pack("H*" , substr($data,16)); 
$res = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $x , MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
return $res;
}
```

I tried with simple:

```
function encrypt_blowfish($data,$key){
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    return $crypttext;
}
```

But it returns strang ASCI chars instead of correct blowfish code. Could somebody explain me why, and what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

C.H.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function decrypt_blowfish($data,$key){
    $iv=pack("H*" , substr($data,0,16));
    $x =pack("H*" , substr($data,16)); 
    $res = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $x , MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    return $res;
}

function encrypt_blowfish($data,$key){
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    return bin2hex($iv . $crypttext);
}

$string = encrypt_blowfish('hello world', 'abc123');
echo 'ENCRYPTED: ' . $string . "\n";
echo 'DECRYPTED: ' . decrypt_blowfish($string, 'abc123');
```

Try that. In the decryption function you are converting from hex to binary, so it is expecting a hex value to be passed. Your encryption function is outputting binary, so you need to convert it to hex with the above change.

Comment: Thank you. It's certain a solution for part of the problem, but decrypt_blowfish(encrypt_blowfish("test",$blowfish_key),$blowfish_key); returns some ASCI chars instead of string "test" Do you maby know why?

Comment: You need to pass the IV to the decrypt function which expects it to be concatenated to the encrypted string so...

return bin2hex($iv . $crypttext);

Comment: The decrypt function also seems to be converting the key from hex to binary as well. Which means the encryption function should be accepting it as binary as well, are you doing that or entering in ASCII chars? If not the keys will not match.

Comment: I fixed it, and posted it as the answer. =o)

Comment: How to use this encryption and decryption?  the encryption function returns nothing.  Is any other files are required?